# Remove part of string in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to remove a part of string from one character, that is:

Source string:

```
manchester united (with nice players)
```

Target string:

```
manchester united
```

Comment: How do you know which part to keep and which part to discard? Without knowing that, it is impossible to answer your question?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. If you have the string which you want to replace you can use the `replace` or `replaceAll` methods of the `String` class. If you are looking to replace a substring you can get the substring using the `substring` API.

For example

```
String str = "manchester united (with nice players)";
System.out.println(str.replace("(with nice players)", ""));
int index = str.indexOf("(");
System.out.println(str.substring(0, index));
```

To replace content within "()" you can use:

```
int startIndex = str.indexOf("(");
int endIndex = str.indexOf(")");
String replacement = "I AM JUST A REPLACEMENT";
String toBeReplaced = str.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
System.out.println(str.replace(toBeReplaced, replacement));
```

Comment: some typo. should be `String toBeReplaced = str.substring(startIndex , endIndex + 1);`

Comment: also would be worth to remove the space: System.out.println(str.replace(" (with nice players)", ""));

Answer (score 36):

**String Replace**

```
String s = "manchester united (with nice players)";
s = s.replace(" (with nice players)", "");
```

**Edit:**

**By Index**

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("(") - 1);
```

Comment: don't forget `s = s.replace(...)`

Comment: It can not be, because what is in parentheses can change. I need to change the string from the character (

Comment: Replace will work but the substring version will not work if the string to remove is in the middle of the larger string.

Answer (score 24):

Use String.Replace():

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/73139

Example:

```
String original = "manchester united (with nice players)";
String newString = original.replace(" (with nice players)","");
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but perhaps because you put Replace in the wrong case?

Comment: Upvoted to negate the effect of a drive-by (i.e., unexplained and apparently specious) down vote.

Comment: It's not necessary that the string will be same as the example given. So you cannot use replace.

Comment: There is performance comparison here , String replace method uses regular expression under the hood. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228992/commons-lang-stringutils-replace-performance-vs-string-replace

Answer (score 12):

```
originalString.replaceFirst("[(].*?[)]", "");
```

https://ideone.com/jsZhSC
*`replaceFirst()` can be replaced by `replaceAll()`*

Answer (score 8):

Using **StringBuilder**, you can replace the following way.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("manchester united (with nice players)");
int startIdx = str.indexOf("(");
int endIdx = str.indexOf(")");
str.replace(++startIdx, endIdx, "");
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use the substring() method of String object.

Here is an example code:

Assumption: I am assuming here that you want to retrieve the string till the first parenthesis

```
String strTest = "manchester united(with nice players)";
/*Get the substring from the original string, with starting index 0, and ending index as position of th first parenthesis - 1 */
String strSub = strTest.subString(0,strTest.getIndex("(")-1);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would at first split the original string into an array of String with a token " (" and the String at position 0 of the output array is what you would like to have.

```
String[] output = originalString.split(" (");

String result = output[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Using StringUtils from commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/)

A null source string will return null. An empty ("") source string will return the empty string. A null remove string will return the source string. An empty ("") remove string will return the source string.

```
String str = StringUtils.remove("Test remove", "remove");
System.out.println(str);
//result will be "Test"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to remove everything after the "(", try this. Does nothing if no parentheses.

```
StringUtils.substringBefore(str, "(");
```

If there may be content after the end parentheses, try this.

```
String toRemove = StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "(", ")");
String result = StringUtils.remove(str, "(" + toRemove + ")");
```

To remove end spaces, use `str.trim()`

> [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) functions are null-, empty-, and no match- safe

Comment: Good solution!!

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin Solution

**If you are removing a specific string from the end, use** `removeSuffix` ([Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-suffix.html))

```
var text = "one(two"
text = text.removeSuffix("(two") // "one"
```

If the suffix does not exist in the string, it just returns the original

```
var text = "one(three"
text = text.removeSuffix("(two") // "one(three"
```

**If you want to remove after a character, use**

```
// Each results in "one"

text = text.replaceAfter("(", "").dropLast(1) // You should check char is present before `dropLast`
// or
text = text.removeRange(text.indexOf("("), text.length)
// or
text = text.replaceRange(text.indexOf("("), text.length, "")
```

You can also check out [`removePrefix`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-prefix.html), [`removeRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-range.html), [`removeSurrounding`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-surrounding.html), and [`replaceAfterLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace-after-last.html) which are similar

**The Full List is here:** ([Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index.html))

Answer (score 1):

```
// Java program to remove a substring from a string
public class RemoveSubString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String master = "1,2,3,4,5";
        String to_remove="3,";

        String new_string = master.replace(to_remove, "");
        // the above line replaces the t_remove string with blank string in master

        System.out.println(master);
        System.out.println(new_string);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace` to fix your string. The following will return everything before a "(" and also strip all leading and trailing whitespace. If the string starts with a "(" it will just leave it as is.

```
str = "manchester united (with nice players)"
matched = str.match(/.*(?=\()/)
str.replace(matched[0].strip) if matched
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Java. It might be derivative of ECMAscript. Do you have some method to make this code work as is in Java?