# How to remove this url from string?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
String description= errex for Screen Share 
https://ednovo.webex.com/ednovo/j.php?ED=224466857&UID=1465621292&RT=MiM0
You can find the meeting notes here https://docs.yahoo.com/a/filter.org/document/d/1Luf_6Q73_Lm30t3x6wHS_4Ztkn7HfXDg4sZZWz-CuVw/edit?usp=sharing
```

I want to remove the url link and end up with this:

```
String description=errex for Screen Share You can find the meeting notes here
```

I tried the following code but it is not detecting the URL:

```
private String removeUrl(String commentstr)
    {
        String commentstr1=commentstr;
        String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr1);
        int i=0;
        while (m.find()) {
            commentstr1=commentstr1.replaceAll(m.group(i),"").trim();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("After url filter" +commentstr1);

        return commentstr1;
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: if you're sure of the fact that url can't have spaces you could easily split string.
Then you could parse all the resulting array with a regex or simply catching (and ignoring) the string wich contains special chars.
If it's ok for you I could arrange a simple class.

Comment: Look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366496/removing-the-url-from-text-using-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will remove urls:

```
description = description.replaceAll("https?://\\S+\\s?", "");
```

Btw the little `\\s?` at the end ensures you don't get double spaces after the URL has been removed from between two spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
String description= "errex for Screen Share https://ednovo.webex.com/ednovo/j.php?ED=224466857&UID=1465621292&RT=MiM0 " +
    "You can find the meeting notes here https://docs.yahoo.com/a/filter.org/document/d/1Luf_6Q73_Lm30t3x6wHS_4Ztkn7HfXDg4sZZWz-CuVw/edit?usp=sharing";

System.out.println(description.replaceAll("\\S+://\\S+", ""));
```