# How to use regular expression to remove url which has $?-()

Tags: java, regex, url, https

Origin string :

```
String str = "others. https://forum.com/thread.jspa?thread$ID=251290(tr)start=75&t-start=0 I recently"
```

Target String:

```
"others. I recently";
```

I applied the 11 votes answer of - [Removing the url from text using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366496/removing-the-url-from-text-using-java/12950893#12950893)
but it didn't work on my url.

Thanks for help.

Comment: As your URL does not contain _spaces_, why not simply split your string this way?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose which way?

Comment: [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) ?

Answer (score 0):

**I.** If you have always the struture : word url word (and url without spaces) you can use :

```
String str = "others. https://forum.com/thread.jspa[...]art=75&t-start=0 I recently";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)http.*\\s(.*)").matcher(str); // (capture1)url (capture2)
String target = "";
if (m.find()) {
    target = m.group(1) + m.group(2);
}
System.out.println(target);  //others. recently
```

The pattern will capture 2 groups, the one before the url, and the one after the space after the url

---

**II.** Iterate over the words of the sentence and keep the ones which does not contains "http" which significate that it's an url

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String word : str.split(" ")) { 
     if (!word.contains("http")) { 
         builder.append(word).append(" "); 
     } 
} 
String target = builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length()-1).toString();
System.out.println(target); //others. recently
```

---

**III.** Same as **II.** but wih streams (ONE LINE solution) :

```
String target = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "))
                      .stream()
                      .filter(word -> !word.contains("http"))
                      .map(word -> word + " ")
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```