# Convert Jsoup element to string

Tags: java, android, string, jsoup

I'm developing an Android app. I need to change an Element in Jsoup to a string so that I can subtract the two.  The code below and     `String value = valueOf(arrT.val());` do not work. I'm not sure how to convert an Element into a string. My code is:

**TestStation.java**

```
public class TestStation extends Activity {
String URL = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=201412abc85d49b2b83f907f9e329eaa&mapid=40380";
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_station);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



Document doc = null;

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Elements elem = doc.select("eta");
for (Element div : elem) {

}Elements elemn = doc.select("eta"); for (Element div : elem) {
Elements arrT = div.select("arrT");
Elements prdt = div.select("prdt");


try {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(prdt.val());
    Date date1 = sdf.parse(arrT.val());
    tv.setText(String.valueOf (prdt));
    long dateDiff = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())>0 ? (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) :(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf1.format(dateDiff);


    }

catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();



 }

}
}
```

It gives me a compile error saying that prdt cannot change from an Element to a string. I would love any help you could give on this, because there is noting online that I can find on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Jsoup [text()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) function

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
Date date2 = sdf.parse(prdt.text());
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the difference between the var function and the text function? Var didn't work, but this did.

Answer (score 1):

try out:

`String value = arrT.val();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");`

Date date = sdf.parse(value);

[see the jsoup apidocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#val%28%29)

Note: the date pattern must match with the format you are passing to the **parse** method.

Additional note: as **doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)** does network calls, consider putting it in an AsyncTask instead of calling directly on the UI Thread (in the onCreate() method).

Comment: This doesn't work, I have the date part okay, but value = null and arrT = 20130922 14:15:16.

Comment: @hichris123 HH:mm:ss this is the format you want but actually that doesn't matter the format is in which your data is that is yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss Check my answer again

Comment: The string in the TextView doesn't display anything, so I don't think that this method works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting date in

Then it should be like this 
and are you forgetting **prdt.val()**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(prdt.val());
```

Comment: the Element prdt actually equals <prdt> 20130922 14:39:23 </prdt> Could this have an affect on why it returns nothing after `Date date2 = sdf.parse(prdt.val());
  Date date1 = sdf.parse(arrT.val());`?

Comment: How can I strip out the <prdt> and </prdt>?

Comment: Check for the values of String.valueOf(prdt.val()) what it is

Comment: It equals <prdt> 20130922 16:33:17 </prdt>. Will this work to strip out the tag? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694984/remove-part-of-string

Comment: use can use this string.replace("<",""); string.replace("/>","");
 string.replace("prdt",""); them trim the string remember prdt changes with arrT so in that case change it

Comment: Problem again is that `}Elements elemn = doc.select("eta"); for (Element div : elem) {
    Elements arrT = div.select("arrT");
    Elements prdt = div.select("prdt");
    String.valueOf(prdt.val());
    String value = String.valueOf(arrT.val());
    tv.setText(String.valueOf (value));` doesn't display anything on the TextView.