# Java - Get Names Of Files In Directory

Tags: java

How would I get the ".txt" from displaying?

```
    File folder = new File("C:/Users/Camaloony/Desktop/Java Stuff/Python Home Control/Users/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        }
```

---

```
g.drawString(listOfFiles[0].getName(), 660, 395);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: And what is your code so far? Without existing code you cannot really expect your question to be answered, right?

Comment: "How would I [...]" => By writing some code.

Comment: I have code to generate the red squares depending on the amount of files in the directory etc... I just didn't know that it would be useful as it is pretty much unrelated to the actual names of the files themselves.

Comment: Turns out I found out how to get the names as well as the .txt -> how would I stop the .txt from dispalying - adding code now

Comment: You could split the string on the '.' and just use the first part of the split array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the ".txt" when you call

```
 g.drawString(listOfFiles[0].getName(), 660, 395);
```

You can call the replace method on the string you get back from listOfFiles[0].getName() like so

```
g.drawString(listOfFiles[0].getName().replace(".txt", ""), 660, 395);
```

This is related to [Remove part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694984/remove-part-of-string) if you'd like to know more about the replace() method or you can check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    File f = new File("E:\\Code\\folder");
    File[] arr = f.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String fileName = arr[i].getName().split("\\.")[0];
        System.out.println(fileName);   
    }
```

This will do the job of removing '.txt' :

```
   getName().split("\\.")[0]
```

Comment: Thank you also for your fast reply, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Happy coding....

Comment: I don't suppose you have Skype Shaggy? For some reason I've been banned from asking questions.