# How can I ignore part of an input in Java?

Tags: java, input, hex

I need to make a program that can convert hexadecimal values to decimal. I got the program to work but I need to make my program display the same output no matter if the hexadecimal value entered contains the "0x" in front or not.

this is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static long hex2decimal(String s){
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        int val = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int d = digits.indexOf(c);
            val = 16*val + d;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long decimal;

        System.out.println("Please enter the hex string:");
        String s = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        decimal = hex2decimal(s);
        System.out.println(decimal);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694984/remove-part-of-string)

Comment: `if (s.startsWith("0x")) { s = s.substring(2); }`

Answer (score 1):

Why should you not using **Integer.parseInt("121",16)**, rather custom logic for converting hex to decimal. Here 16 is radix telling number is hexadecimal and will be converted to decimal.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("121",16));
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` does not ignore `0x`, which I believe is what the asker is trying to do.

Comment: You can simply replace or ignore that before passing to parseInt

Comment: Yes, but that is what the asker is trying to achieve — not the conversion part. I suggest adding it to your code.